# Solving an inverse problem $- \Delta u = f$ where we know that $f$ is harmonic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, inverse-problems

Let $\Omega$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the inverse problem
$$
- \Delta u = f,
$$
where we want to find $f$ when we are given $\partial_\nu u = g$ on $\partial \Omega$ and we know that $f$ is harmonic.

A hint for this problem says introduce a new function $v = \Delta u$. So in this case the equation becomes
$$
-v = f
$$
and taking the Laplacian of both sides we get
$$
-\Delta v = \Delta f = 0.
$$
For the boundary condition I have
$$
v = \Delta u \Longleftrightarrow \int_\Omega v = \int_\Omega \Delta u = \int_{\partial \Omega} \partial_\nu u = \int_{\partial \Omega} g. 
$$
So we have the following problem for $v$:
$$
- \Delta v = 0, \\
\int_\Omega v = \int_{\partial \Omega} g.
$$
Is this correct? If so, how do we solve this last expression for $v$?

Comment: Do you need anaylitical solution or just numerical solution?

Comment: If $f$ is continuously differentiable up to the boundary, $\partial_\nu v = \partial_\nu f $ at the boundary can be your new condition. So you have a Neumann problem for $v$